# Having problem with path (nodejs botbuilder)

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, botframework, dirname

I'm working on a bot using Bot Framework, .env file and a JSON file. 
The problem is I can't seem to get the icon to show up unless I set the path manually as shown below:

`var invite = new Welcome(process.env.IconUrl = "C:/Users/2203609/Desktop/Mybot/bot.jpg");`

That is not a practical way as we will need to change the path manually every time we transfer over to another computer. So I came up with this idea. I will show my .js, .env and .json files.

I create 3 variables namely:

.js:

```
const loc = '\\bot.jpg';
const pathname = __dirname;
const assa = pathname + loc;

class welcome(){
    constructor(IconUrl, botVersion) {
    this.IconUrl = IconUrl
    this.BotVersion = botVersion
}

}
async Menu(turnContext) {
    var invite = new Welcome(process.env.IconUrl = assa);
    await turnContext.sendActivity({
        attachments: [invite.welcome()]
    });
}
```

**.env**:

```
IconUrl =

"items": [{
     "type": "Image",
     "style": "Person",
     "url": "%IconUrl%",
     "size": "Large"
  }],
```

The output for this is:

> [onTurnError]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 633
>
> UPDATE: the variable pathname cannot be used as parameter in welcome class.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in how you structured your code. If you wish to display an image you need to use a card. In the example below, I'm using a hero card.

Also, the 'onTurn' method must keep that name. You can create other methods within the class that have their own name. These would reflect different steps within a waterfall dialog. You can read more about waterfall dialogs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

```js
const { ActivityTypes, CardFactory } = require('botbuilder');
const loc = '\\bot.jpg';
const pathname = __dirname;
const assa = pathname + loc;

const hero = CardFactory.heroCard(
    'Hero Card',
    CardFactory.images([assa])
);

class Welcome {
    constructor(IconUrl, botVersion) {
        this.IconUrl = IconUrl;
        this.BotVersion = botVersion;
    }

    async onTurn(turnContext) {
        if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
            if (!turnContext.responded) {
                const reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
                reply.attachments = [hero];
                return await turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports.Welcome = Welcome;
```

I would recommend reading thru the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Even more so, I would recommend you look over the various samples on the [Botbuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) GitHub repo. Each sample builds on the previous and introduces core ideas and best practices.

Hope of help!